# simple calculator with button not working

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was trying to make a simple calculator using buttons but when submitting the form, the result element seems to be out of range since my button click event stores the calculation result, Thus, makes it impossible to call it from from another function. I also tried using 'var' but it did not help. I am relatively new to the programming world ,so please explain thoroughly if possible. here is the code:-

```
//HTML

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="number" name="num1" id="num1">
        <button name="calc" id="add" value="add">+</button>
        <button name="calc" id="sub" value="sub">-</button>
        <button name="calc" id="mul" value="mul">*</button>
        <button name="calc" id="divi" value="divi">/</button>
        <input type="number" name="num2" id="num2">
        <button type="submit" value="result" id="res">=</button>
        <input type="number" name="result" id="num3">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
//JAVASCRIPT

    <script>
        const form = document.querySelector('form');
        const btn = document.querySelector('button');

        btn.addEventListener('click', e =>{
            const num1 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#num1').value);
            const num2 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#num2').value);

            if(btn.value === 'add'){
                var num3 = num1 + num2;
            }
            else if(btn.value === 'sub'){
                var num3 =  num1 - num2;
            }
            else if(btn.value === 'mul'){
                var num3 =  num1 * num2;
            }
            else if(btn.value === 'divi'){
                var num3 =  num1 / num2;
            }
            else{
                console.log('that is not a number!');
            }
        });

        form.addEventListener('submit', e =>{
            e.preventDefault();
            form.result.value = num3;
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `var num3 = ""` outside of your event listener at the top;

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
var num3 = "";
```

And inside your event listener, use it like below for your cases:

```
num3 = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
```

You are using `querySelector` which would give you only the first dom element, you need to change it to `querySelectorAll` to get all the button in the DOM, then loop it through to find the value for each button.

Below is the fiddle which works for all the operators.
https://jsfiddle.net/9w3hjyk2/2/

Complete code:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const button = document.querySelectorAll('button');
var num3 = "";

button.forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
        const num1 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#num1').value);
        const num2 = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#num2').value);
        if (btn.value === 'add') {
            num3 = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
        } else if (btn.value === 'sub') {
            console.log("num3", num1 - num2)
            num3 = parseInt(num1) - parseInt(num2);
        } else if (btn.value === 'mul') {
            num3 = parseInt(num1) * parseInt(num2);
        } else if (btn.value === 'divi') {
            num3 = parseInt(num1) / parseInt(num2);
        } else {
            console.log('that is not a number!');
        }
    });
});


form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    form.result.value = num3;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing an `onclick` event. Study my code and get some idea

```js
      function dis(val) 
         { 
             document.getElementById("result").value+=val 
         } 
           

         function solve() 
         { 
             let x = document.getElementById("result").value 
             let y = eval(x) 
             document.getElementById("result").value = y 
         } 
           
       
         function clr() 
         { 
             document.getElementById("result").value = "" 
         }
```

```css
      .title{ 
         margin-bottom: 10px; 
         text-align:center; 
         width: 210px; 
         color:White; 
         border: solid black 2px; 
         } 
  
         input[type="button"] 
         { 
         background-color:whitesmoke; 
         color: black; 
         border: solid black 2px; 
         width:100% 
         } 
  
         input[type="text"] 
         { 
         background-color:white; 
         border: solid black 2px; 
         width:100% 
         }
```

```html
      
   </head> 
   <body> 
      <table border="1"> 
         <tr> 
            <td colspan="3"><input type="text" id="result"/></td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="c" onclick="clr()"/> </td> 
         </tr> 
         <tr> 
           
            <td><input type="button" value="1" onclick="dis('1')"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="2" onclick="dis('2')"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="3" onclick="dis('3')"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="/" onclick="dis('/')"/> </td> 
         </tr> 
         <tr> 
            <td><input type="button" value="4" onclick="dis('4')"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="5" onclick="dis('5')"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="6" onclick="dis('6')"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="-" onclick="dis('-')"/> </td> 
         </tr> 
         <tr> 
            <td><input type="button" value="7" onclick="dis('7')"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="8" onclick="dis('8')"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="9" onclick="dis('9')"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="dis('+')"/> </td> 
         </tr> 
         <tr> 
            <td><input type="button" value="." onclick="dis('.')"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="0" onclick="dis('0')"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="=" onclick="solve()"/> </td> 
            <td><input type="button" value="*" onclick="dis('*')"/> </td> 
         </tr> 
      </table> 
   </body> 
</html>
```